# What does the below mininet command mean?

Tags: networking, command, mininet, sdn

I'm starting to learn mininet and I know that the below mininet command will create a default tree topology with a depth of 2 and a fanout of 3. But I didn't understand what this exactly means? Can someone please explain?

`sudo mn --topo tree,depth=2,fanout=3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The execution of that command will create a topology with 9 hosts (*fanout ^ depth*, in this case *3^2*) connected to 4 switches (*fanout + 1*, in this case *3+1*).

The resultant topology will look something like this:

```
                   h2  h3
                    | /
           s1 ———  s2 — h1
             | \
             |  \
       h8 — s4   s3  — h4
          / |     |  \
        h9  h7    h5  h6
```

Answer (score 1):

A tree topology has a single switch with others connected to it based on a fanout number. This continues based on the depth specified.

Below are few of the examples.

Depth = 1, fanout = 2
[image]

Depth = 2, fanout =2
[image]

Depth = 2, fanout = 3
[image]

Depth = 3, fanout = 2
[image]